# Printf doesn't work with a variable value

Tags: c, printf

The last printf instruction doesn't work with key = 3. I can't understand why, can someone help me? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char string[100];
int key;
int jump;
printf("Enter the text: ");
fgets(string, 100, stdin);
printf("Enter crypto key: ");
scanf("%d", &key);
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
{
    jump = 0;
    if (string[i] + key > 126)
    {
        jump = 95;
    }
    string[i] = string[i] + key - jump;
}
printf("The crypto text in key %d is: %s", key, string);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code involving the variable `jump` looks incomplete.  I can easily imagine that, depending on what characters are being encrypted, one of the replaced characters might end up being nonprintable, thus damaging the encrypted string and, making it, well, nonprintable.  What input string were you you trying to encrypt with key 3?

Comment: More importantly, any string you read using `fgets` is likely to end in a newline character, `\n`.  And your code is also trying to encrypt that character, turning it into some other control character.  For key = 3, you turn `\n` into CR (aka `\r`), a carriage return, which will lead to some weird output.

Comment: Everything i try to encrypt with key 3 is not printed. Every phrase both with space and without space.

Comment: It's because of the carriage return, and the way your environment is displaying it.

Comment: One fix would be to remove the carriage return after calling `fgets`, and before encrypting.  There are many questions here on SO on how to do that.  One is [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776).

Comment: just for that i set the for until i<strlen(string) because strlen doesn't count \n.

Comment: Who told you `strlen` doesn't count the `\n`?  It certainly does.

Comment: oh so that's the point. Thank you, i'll try to solve it with your advices.

Comment: an if i just set the for until i <  strlen(string) -1 ?

Comment: Yes, that might work.  Did you try it?

Comment: Yeah friend, it works. Thank you so much, i learnt the lesson.